# hisafer installation - how do I solve hard-coded installation path?

Tags: r, modeling

I am installing the hisafer package (for biophysical modeling) following instructions from author(s) lead by Kevin Wolz:

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("kevinwolz/hisafer")
```

here I got the answer:

```
...
write_param_file                        html  
write_weather                           html  
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
** testing if installed package can be loaded from final location
** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path
ERROR: hard-coded installation path: please report to the package maintainer and use '--no-staged-install'
* removing 'C:/Users/houska/Documents/R/R-3.6.0/library/hisafer'
Error in i.p(...) : 
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘C:/Users/houska/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpI5hUAl/file32dc572b4098/hisafer_1.4.14.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

the following commands do not work, then:

```
library(hisafer)
vignette("hisafer-vignette")
```

What should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

This is related to the [staged installation](https://developer.r-project.org/Blog/public/2019/02/14/staged-install/) of packages introduced with R 3.6.0. You can disable it by passing the `--no-staged-install` option to `R CMD INSTALL` (as suggested by the error message):

```
devtools::install_github("kevinwolz/hisafer", INSTALL_opts="--no-staged-install")
```