# Cannot load R package GLM3r on my macbook with Apple M1 chip

Tags: r, installation, r-library

I am trying to install GLM3r in my mac Pro M1(12.6)

I use this code :
devtools::install_github("GLEON/GLM3r", ref = "GLMv.3.1.0a3")
and I got this error :

Downloading GitHub repo GLEON/GLM3r@GLMv.3.1.0a3
── R CMD build
✔ checking for file ‘/private/var/folders/8p/db7_6hmd27b8x9mzg6qh_5k00000gn/T/Rtmp3as7Dn/remotes45c6c103ec1/GLEON-GLM3r-a3c1fa0/DESCRIPTION’ ...
─ preparing ‘GLM3r’:
✔ checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...
─ checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
─ checking for empty or unneeded directories
─ building ‘GLM3r_3.1.2.tar.gz’

installing source package ‘GLM3r’ ...
** using staged installation
** R
** exec
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
** checking absolute paths in shared objects and dynamic libraries
ERROR: some hard-coded temporary paths could not be fixed

removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64/Resources/library/GLM3r’
Warning message:
In i.p(...) :
installation of package ‘/var/folders/8p/db7_6hmd27b8x9mzg6qh_5k00000gn/T//Rtmp3as7Dn/file45c1e882854/GLM3r_3.1.2.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

I would appreciate it if someone could help me to fix this problem. I don't have any clue how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix it by setting --no-staged-install parameter.

```
devtools::install_github("GLEON/GLM3r", ref = "GLMv.3.1.0a3", INSTALL_opts="--no-staged-install")
```

You can read more about it here:
https://blog.r-project.org/2019/02/14/staged-install/index.html

And, here is an example of a similar issue that is fixed by --no-staged-install parameter:
[hisafer installation - how do I solve hard-coded installation path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56365021/hisafer-installation-how-do-i-solve-hard-coded-installation-path)

Comment: Thank you .. yes it works for me now .. however I still have problem with glmtools . 
how did you install glmtools then ?
I used both : 

devtools::install_github("USGS-R/glmtools") 

and
devtools::install_github("USGS-R/glmtools", ref='ggplot_overhaul')

but when I execute glm_version().. I dont get response

Comment: I followed their installation method here: https://github.com/GLEON/glmtools/tree/main

Even though, it shows build failed in github repo, I was able to install it with 
# if needed: install.packages('remotes')
remotes::install_github('usgs-r/glmtools')

I am not sure about these packages, but when I run glm_version() it results in '6' - even runnable before installing glm_tools (so, should be a dependency that is already installed). Maybe, try with a fresh R as there might be some complications with current libraries...